# Mod Rewrite and Using PHP's GET for URL's When not Following the Rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I couldn't think of a good title for this, it's hard to explain.
Basically, I have mod_rewrite setup on my server. It turns each `?a=1&b=2&c=3 etc into /1/2/3/`

I want to implement a feature where I can do something like this: `/login/?return_url=/home/`
The return_url would change depending on where the user was last. I know there are other methods of finding out the return url, but I would like to keep it in the URL.

My issue is that the following does not work: `/login/?return_url=/home/`

However, `/login.php?return_url=/home/` does work.

Why can't PHP see the `return_url` variable in the first (preferred) situation?

Here's my current code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ /?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ /?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ /?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: maybe you'll get more chances to have an answer if you show us the mod_rewrite rules youhave, don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`QSA` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is probably what you're looking for:

> `'qsappend|QSA'` (query string append)
>    This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to
>   add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

E.g.,

```
RewriteRule ^something/([0-9]+)$ something.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Will let `something/9?key=val` go to `something.php?id=9&key=val`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm a bit of a newb at all this >.<
I'm not entirely sure how to add that flag. Do I put it next to the [L]. ie: [L|QSA] ?

Comment: @Jack delimit with a comma (`,`), not a pipe (`|`): `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks, it saved me a lot of hassle, because I was going to manually parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`...