# Using .htaccess RewriteRule to interpret multiple $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mod Rewrite and Using PHP’s GET for URL’s When not Following the Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814977/mod-rewrite-and-using-phps-get-for-urls-when-not-following-the-rules)

I've been scratching my head over this for days... I have a instance where a URL needs to pass different variables on a `$_GET` string.

I'm looking to parse the following URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/1/count/?var1=a&var2=b
```

Basically, I need to parse *`count`* as a `$_GET['var3']` variable along with other additional vars appended after the trailing slash (*`?var1=a&var2=b`*).

I've tried the following along with many other options, but it results in a 404:

```
RewriteRule ^1/(count|list|detail)$/$ /1/service.php?method=$1
RewriteRule ^1/(count|list|detail)$/$ /1/service.php?method=$1&$2?
```

I've scoured many docs and answers, but I can't find an applicable answer and admit, it's driving me slowly insane!

Any help would be graciously accepted and appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for `[QSA]` or do you have different URL schemes to match? Why do you have two `$` end markers in the regex?

Comment: Only one URL schema and I've got two $ as I understood that each could be marked as interpreting a different variable ($1, $2 - if both were listed).

Comment: In the replacement part, yes. But only if you have two match groups. That's a different meaning than in the regex.

Comment: @mario Got it. Understand multiple matching groups, just failed to appreciate the [QSA] option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?1/(count|list|detail)/?$ /1/service.php?method=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

you want to use [QSA], Query String Append.  Read about it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).  If this is what you want in your browser:

`http://www.domain.com/1/count/?var1=a&var2=b`

You should put this in your htaccess file

`RewriteRule ^(count|list|detail)/$ /service.php [QSA]`

I removed some of the things from your rule above, not knowing your system, I'm not sure what they were there for. What is the `1` and the duplicate `$` for?

This rule will send `domain.com/count/?t=5` to `domain.com/service.php?t=5`

Comment: No. '1' just maps to a directory /1/ where service.php is located. But would this list/use 'count' as a $_GET variable in addition to 't' in your example?

Comment: +1 as you helped drive the answer I was looking for. Thanks.